# Cookies arent being detected in php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, cookies

Im not sure where im going wrong. I have a form that when the contents of the form get processed and sent to the database it also sets a cookie

```
setcookie("bgremkey",$checkkey, time()+2592000);
```

then it will redirect the user back to the page they came from. All of this works fine (bar the cookie bit)

then i have it set at the top of every page providing there isnt an session active to check to see if the cookie exists and if it does to redirect but it wont work. im sure that the cookie is there but it wont pick it up

```
<?php
                if(isset($_COOKIE['bgremkey']))
                {

                    header("location:'Check.php?cklog=1");
                }
```

?>

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var acookie = ReadCookie("bgremkey");
if(acookie.length != 0)
 { 
  window.location = " Check.php?cklog=1";
 }
```

this code doesnt generate any errors but it also doesnt do anything. i have tried putting it in the  of the page but that didnt work so i then tried the body and that didnt work either 
the check page does a bunch of other stuff but thats not the problem since the redirect never happens

i checked the cookies through chrome and the cookie exists and its path is / so the problem is definitely with reading them. it exists but for some reason cant be detected

Comment: What is the single apostrophe before Check.php? header("location:'Check.php?cklog=1")

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

`setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time);` will only set it for the current path

Whereas: `setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time,"/");`  will set the cookie for all pages/folders on that domain (note the 4th argument containing the *path* ).

If you press CTRL+SHIFT+J in google chrome, and click on the Resources tab, you can find the cookies and the path it is valid in. I'd check that out. perhaps this is why?

Comment: doesnt seem to matter the cookie is there in the / directory anyway